# ping to 8.8.8.8 stable with 0 packet loss but ping to google.com have packet loss

Tags: networking, router, dns, ping

when i ping google.com i have a ping of average 50 with 7% packet loss but surprisingly when i ping 8.8.8.8 the ping is average 40 with 0 packet loss (for about 300 packet both tests), and my internet provider only see problems when there is packet loss to 8.8.8.8 and nothing else, what could be the reason of this? because i can feel these packet loss while gaming.

i tried these commands:

- ipconfig /release
- ipconfig /flushdns
- ipconfig /renew
- netsh int ip set dns
- netsh winsock reset

Comment: Which DNS servers are you using?

Comment: What about 8.8.4.4?

Comment: in ipv4 i have it to automatic 
in my network propreties i have these info :
DNS servers: 192.168.0.1    //router log in page
DNS domain name: www.tendawifi.com
DNS connection suffix: www.tendawifi.com //which also lead to router log in page

Comment: 8.8.4.4 is same as 8.8.8.8 stable with no packet loss